# Is this strange function converting string to binary?

Tags: c, binary, unsigned-char

I am doing bug fixing on a old c code in our system ( strangely enough, it's not standard c. It is not compiled by gcc ). I come to this code which seems to be converting a string to binary code in unsigned char format. The logic puzzle me ( bold part ). Does this make any sense to you guys?

I need to understand this code because I have to copy this and reuse it on another string whose length is not 13 but 11.

```
char l_call_dest_no[25];
int l_loop_cnt;
unsigned char l_bcd_byte;
unsigned char l_call_dest_no_in_bcd[13];

...some other code as input...

    for (l_loop_cnt = 0; l_loop_cnt < 13; l_loop_cnt++)
            {
                l_bcd_byte = '\0';
                switch (l_call_dest_no[l_loop_cnt * 2])
                {
                    case '0':
                    case '1':
                    case '2':
                    case '3':
                    case '4':
                    case '5':
                    case '6':
                    case '7':
                    case '8':
                    case '9':
                        l_bcd_byte = (l_call_dest_no[l_loop_cnt * 2] - 48) * 16;
                        break;
                    case 'A':
                        l_bcd_byte = 10 * 16;
                        break;
                    case 'B':
                        l_bcd_byte = 11 * 16;
                        break;
                    case 'C':
                        l_bcd_byte = 12 * 16;
                        break;
                    case 'D':
                        l_bcd_byte = 13 * 16;
                        break;
                    case 'E':
                        l_bcd_byte = 14 * 16;
                        break;
                    case 'F':
                    case ' ':
                        l_bcd_byte = 15 * 16;
                        break;
                    default:
                        printf("*** invalid call destination number ***\n");
                        return_status = FAILURE;
                        break;
                }

                if (l_loop_cnt < 12)
                {
                    switch (l_call_dest_no[l_loop_cnt * 2 + 1])
                    {
                        case '0':
                        case '1':
                        case '2':
                        case '3':
                        case '4':
                        case '5':
                        case '6':
                        case '7':
                        case '8':
                        case '9':
                            l_bcd_byte = l_bcd_byte + (l_call_dest_no[l_loop_cnt * 2 + 1] - 48) ;
                            break;
                        case 'A':
                            l_bcd_byte = l_bcd_byte + 10;
                            break;
                        case 'B':
                            l_bcd_byte = l_bcd_byte + 11;
                            break;
                        case 'C':
                            l_bcd_byte = l_bcd_byte + 12;
                            break;
                        case 'D':
                            l_bcd_byte = l_bcd_byte + 13;
                            break;
                        case 'E':
                            l_bcd_byte = l_bcd_byte + 14;
                            break;
                        case 'F':
                        case ' ':
                            l_bcd_byte = l_bcd_byte + 15;
                            break;
                        default:
                            printf("*** invalid call destination number ***\n");
                            return_status = FAILURE;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                    l_bcd_byte = l_bcd_byte + 15;

                if (l_bcd_byte == 255)
                    l_call_dest_no_in_bcd[l_loop_cnt] = '\0';
                else
                {
                    l_call_dest_no_in_bcd[l_loop_cnt] = l_bcd_byte;
                        l_call_dest_no_bcd_length++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg that's not the question.

Comment: It seems you run into a BCD encoder/decoder: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal

Comment: I believe you shouldn't copy this. You should rather *fix it* because you could get it down to a few lines of code.

Comment: I first thought I ended up in The Daily WTF

Comment: Now I know what it is doing......Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code converts strings containing hexadecimal (e.g. `"002A40FF160AD"`) to an array of bytes containing the values in raw binary (e.g. `{0x00, 0x2A, 0x40, 0xFF, 0x16, 0x0A, 0xDF}`). The function has a few gotchas:

- Strangely enough, the string length isn't even, so an additional 'F' is implied to be at the end of the string. (the `else l_bcd_byte = l_bcd_byte + 15;`).
- Additional oddity is that `"FF"` is converted to 0x00.
- Both `'F'` and `' '` (a space) are treated as an `'F'`
- The function works also as a string to packed-decimal (BCD) converter, because packed decimals look like hexadecimal numbers using only digits 0-9 (e.g. 15 in decimal is `0x15` in packed decimal). <strike>The final `F` complicates this functionality, though.</strike>

**EDIT**

The final F makes packed-decimal format actually *easier* to use: an F at the end of a packed-decimal number means that the number is unsigned.

Comment: With your help I understand more. It take 2 char at a time and combine their value to a unsigned char. For example, if the string is '00195232943     ', it will take '00', '19', '52', '32', '94', '3 ' and append a '\0' to indicate end. Under hex editor, it will show '00195232943F'. In normal editor, it will show '00195232943'. Thus enable the text to be transfer in binary mode. Pretty nasty.

Answer (score 1):

That's a custom BCD transformer. Look-up the BCD format and get a good grasp of how to transform numbers from BCD format to regular numbers.

Afterwards, if you're migrating old code, make sure you move the entire code block in a function. Even if it has a bug. Old code might depend on that bug. After you prove that all the code-paths leading to the old code are covered and bug-free you can start fixing/changing behavior.

I do have one question for you, why is it not standard C code? What's the error that gcc gives you on that code? What does your -std= argument look like?
(I would've asked that by replying to your post but apparently I'm not allowed to.)

Comment: Hmmm. I don't know whether it is not standard c but it has some behaviour which I haven't seen from a gcc compiled c program. For example, it won't accept // as comment.

Comment: Yes, // comments were introduced in the C99 standard. gcc(1) uses gnu89 by default, which is the C90 standard + GNU extensions. So if you want // comments you better add -std=C99 to your CFLAGS.